# Transfer to another page in AJAX call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel

Hi there is it possible to redirect to another page using ajax? I have this piece of code that I have been working on to try this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document.body).on('click', '#btnPrintPrev', function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/pdfdatacal',
        data: {
          dummydata: "This is a dummy data"
        },
       });
});
  </script>
```

Now it should be able to carry data to another page and redirect there. Problem is it doesn't.

This is what I am using in my route

```
Route::get('/pdfdatacal', 'GenerateReportController@pdfdatacal');
```

Then in the controller

```
 public function pdfdatacal(Request $request) {
        return $request->data['dummydata'];

    }
```

My expected result should be a blank page containing the value of `dummydata` but it doesn't do that in my code. How do I accomplish this?

Comment: hello there, are you trying to pass data from the ajax to the pdfdatacal ?

Comment: yes I am trying to access `data` on pdfdatacal

Comment: added an answer .. hope it helps ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first your ajax must be something like

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/pdfdatacal',
    method: 'post',
    data: { dummydata: "This is a dummy data" },
    dataType: "JSON",
    success: function(response){
        console.log(response); // just to check if the data is being passed
        // do something you want if ever . 
    }
});
```

then in your routes

```
Route::post('/pdfdatacal', 'GenerateReportController@pdfdatacal');
```

in your controller

```
public function pdfdatacal(Request $request) {
    return response()->json($request->dummydata);
}
```

hope it helps ..

Comment: is possible to do multiple responses? say in my `data` I have `dummydata` and `dummydata2` which both have values, how do I access both of them in the `success response`?

Comment: for example .. your controller returns an array like ..
`return response()->json(['hello'=>'world','hi'=>'universe']);` in your JS you can access it as `response.data.hello` and `response.data.hi`

Comment: or if your not using associated array like `return response()->json(['hello','world','hi','universe']);` what you can do is either loop it using jquery each of `response.data` .. or manually call it as `response.data[0]` -to `response.data[3]`

Comment: how do i send that success response to another page then if my `data` gets big I don't think my route url can handle it. This was my goal from the beginning. To send send an array of objects/array in my controller after getting values from jquery.

Comment: `window.location.href = "http://yourwebsite.com/targetlocation/var1/" + response.data.var1;` 

then in the route , `Route::get('/targetlocation/var1/{val1}', 'GenerateReportController@sampleFunction');` 

then in function `public function sampleFunction($var1) {`

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
window.location.href = "http://yourwebsite.com/pdfdatacal";
```

In your success call

The idea is that you send data to your controller, it sends back a response, then you redirect from javascript to where you want.

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/pdfdatacal',
    type : 'GET',
    data : {
        dummydata: "This is a dummy data"
    },
    success : function(data) {              
        window.location.href = "http://yourwebsite.com/pdfdatacal";
    }
});
```

But if your controller does nothing with the data you send, then you don't need to use ajax at all, simple redirect using javascript.

Answer (score 0):

you could use `window.location.assign('your URL here!');` in the success.

```
success : function(data) {              
        window.location.assign('your URL here!');
    }
```